# using $locationProvider in page reload doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in case of eliminating # from address url , I tried to use $location provider in my router. at the first load changing root to another url works. but when I reload the new page it self i get `Cannot GET /functionalists`

this is my config:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider' ,
    function ($routeProvider , $locationProvider ) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/functionalists',
            {
                templateUrl: '/public/app/views/functionalities/functionalities.html',
                controller: 'FuntionalitiesController'


            })
            .when('/setting',
            {
                templateUrl: '/public/app/views/setting/setting.html',
                controller: 'SettingController'
            })
            .when('/guide',
            {
                templateUrl: '/public/app/views/guide/guide.html',
                controller: 'GuideController'
            })
            .when('/contact',
            {
                templateUrl: '/public/app/views/contactus/contactus.html',
                controller: ''
            })
            .when('/token',{

            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    }]);
```

this is the controller which I use for redirect

```
app.controller('MainViewController', ['$scope', '$location', 'MainViewFactory', function ($scope, $location, MainViewFactory) {

    $scope.functions = function () {
        $location.path("/functionalists")
    };
    $scope.setting = function () {
        $location.path("/setting")
    };
    $scope.guide = function () {
        $location.path("/guide")
    };
    $scope.contactUs = function () {
        $location.path("/contact")
    };

}]);
```

please help me in this issue!

Comment: From a cursory glance, everything looks okay. Could you create a plunkr or similar to replicate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this at your server side (back end)
Actually the request http://server.net/setting this way will take you to the webserver and your webserver does not reply you properly,

in appache and php index page I use something like this:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3000"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]


<FilesMatch "\.php$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "index[0-9]?\.php$">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

If you do not have access on your backend, you should use the hashtags, unfortunately

Comment: Probably good  to look into the docs for UI Router to solve this.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
when using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: the problem here is that I'm using phonegap server which I don't have access to the server side

Comment: Salam, You DO need to server side setting brother unfortunately.