# changing an angularjs application url before loading

Tags: angularjs

I'm using an instagram api which the result is redirecting to my app. problem is here that instgram doesn't accept the url including # 
for example :http://localhost:3000/#/functionalists is not accepted because of `/#/` 
my app is using angularjs which uses this url style for routing . is there any way to change the url redirected by instagram to a compatible on with my app??

Comment: Will instagram accept &35; instead of #? Will Angular?

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be easier to change the way you redirect in your app.
If You're using $locationprovider yo can set the html5mode to true, and then change your base to '/' that way the '#' simbol would not be used.

Comment: yes but there is problem in that case which i don't have access to server side and it causes the problem below
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479948/using-locationprovider-in-page-reload-doesnt-work